# Selenium chromedriver is not working(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

I am trying to create a program to automate my Chrome browser. But the selenium chrome driver is not working. It opens up chrome for 1-2 seconds and then automatically canceled. Then it gives these errors.

Answer (score 1):

You have a basic syntax problem.
Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\python projects\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com")
```

Comment: Indeed. I would add, if you are a beginner with python you might be well served to do some education/practice with the language before jumping into using the python webdriver bindings for selenium.

Answer (score 0):

That error means your Chromdriver.exe is not updated based on your Google Chrom version.
In the error says your version of Google Chrome is 90.0.443.212.

Here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/ you can download the chromedriver.exe

[image]

Download the chromdriver and then replace it, this should do the work.